# Generic method - "unchecked conversion to conform to T from the type" warning

Tags: java, generics

If I have the following:

```
public interface Foo {
   <T extends Foo> T getBlah();
}

public class Bar implements Foo {
   public Bar getBlah() {  
      return this;
   }
}
```

I get a warning in eclipse about the 'getBlah' implementation in class Bar:

```
- Type safety: The return type Bar for getBlah from the type Bar needs unchecked conversion to conform to T from the type 
 Foo
```

How can I fix this? And why am I getting the warning?

Thanks

Comment: You wrote that the type returned by `getBlah` must extend the interface `Foo`. But `Bar` does not, it implements it.

Comment: 'extends' covers interface implementations

Comment: A case of over-genericization. See Joeblackdev's comment and Alessandro Santini's answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are overriding a method from your interface, so your implementation you should match the signature from your specification:

```
public class Bar {
    @Override
    public <T extends Foo> T getBlah() {  
        return this;
    }
}
```

Now, if you were instead planning on creating a specifically parametized override of the entire implementation, then you need to specify the generic type as a part of the interface definition:

```
public interface Foo<T extends Foo<T>> {
    T getBlah();
}

public class Bar implements Foo<Bar> {
   @Override
   public Bar getBlah() {  
      return this;
   }
}
```

Comment: And why, in God's name, should he be inferring a generic type that is not used anywhere?

Comment: I don't assume that this is his entire code. Because you know what they say about assumptions ...

Comment: The first line should be `public interface Foo<T extends Foo<T>>` or `public interface Foo<T extends Foo<?>>`.

Answer (score 4):

```
<T extends Foo> T getBlah();
```

means that a caller can request *any* type as T to be returned. So no matter what class the object is, I can request *some other random* subclass of Foo of my choosing to be returned. The only value that such a method could validly return is `null` (unless it does unsafe casts), which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what do you want to accomplish here but I think that returning Foo would be OK:

```
interface Foo {

  public Foo getBlah();

}
```

as you are not using the generic type anywhere in the parameters.