# Issue with Java type parameters for return values

Tags: java, type-parameter

I've tried to condense this issue down to the smallest amount of code that I could.

I have defined a table structure, like a database table, with the `Row` and `Table` classes below.  A `Table` is essentially a list of `Row`.  I want subclasses to define their particular flavor of `Table` and `Row` and I want the compiler to catch inappropriate attempts to put rows of one type into tables of an incompatible type.

The abstract `Agent` class provides a method to take parameters and return a table that takes rows of type `T`.  I have defined three methods to illustrate the problem that I am having.

The `FinalAgent`, `FinalTable`, and `FinalRow` classes define implementations of the `Agent`, `Table`, and `Row` classes.  Ultimately, what I want is `method2a`, which takes a list of parameters and returns a table of type `FinalTable`.

```
public abstract class Row {}
public abstract class Table<T extends Row> {}
public abstract class Agent {
    public <T extends Row> Table<T> method1(List<String> parameter) {
        return null;
    }
    public <T extends Row> Table<T> method2a(List<String> parameter) {
        return null;
    }
    public <T extends Row> Table<T> method2b(String parameter) {
        return null;
    }
}

public class FinalRow extends Row {}
public class FinalTable extends Table<FinalRow> {}
public class FinalAgent extends Agent {
    @Override
    public <T extends Row> Table<T> method1(List<String> parameter) {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public FinalTable method2a(List<String> parameter) {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public FinalTable method2b(String parameter) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

At the bottom:

- `method1` of `FinalAgent` compiles, but I have to write `Table<FinalRow> t1 = new FinalAgent().method1(null);` in order to call the method.
- `method2a` of `FinalAgent` I changed the return type to `FinalTable` to reflect what I am actually returning (I want to write `FinalTable t2a = new FinalAgent().method2a(null);`), but the compiler produces the error: **The method method2a(List) of type FinalAgent must override or implement a supertype method**
- `method3` I changed the parameter from a `List` to a `String`.  The method compiles OK but gives me a type safety warning, which I can at least work with.

So, finally, the question: Is it a compiler bug that `method2a` in `FinalAgent` does not compile yet `method2b` does compile?

I might as well also ask, is there a better way to do what I am doing?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Where's the raw type?

Comment: @shmosel My mistake, I missed the generic type in the declaration of `FinalTable`.

Comment: It is a curious discrepancy.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381712/generic-method-unchecked-conversion-to-conform-to-t-from-the-type-warning

Comment: Note that adding `<T extends Row>` to `method2a` and `method2b` in `FinalAgent` both result in the same error: *The return type is incompatible with Agent.method2x(xxx)*.

Comment: This error occurred only in case of passing parameterized params to the method(Example any collection framework classes). Still wondering why? may be due to type eraser.

Answer (score 8):

It's not clear why you're parameterizing the methods. You're promising to return a `Table<T>`, but your method can't identify `T` at runtime because of type erasure. You probably want to parameterize the entire `Agent` class instead:

```
public abstract class Agent<T extends Table<?>> {
    public T method1(List<String> parameter) {
        return null;
    }
    public T method2a(List<String> parameter) {
        return null;
    }
    public T method2b(String parameter) {
        return null;
    }
}

public class FinalAgent extends Agent<FinalTable> {
    @Override
    public FinalTable method1(List<String> parameter) {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public FinalTable method2a(List<String> parameter) {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public FinalTable method2b(String parameter) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

As for your initial question, I can't make sense of the discrepancy or the warning message on `method2b`.

Answer (score 1):

Using a method parameter at a single place means the parameter is usually unnecessary

With methods like that in `Agent`, `FinalAgent` compiles fine:

```
public Table<? extends Row> method2a(List<String> parameter) {
    return null;
}
public Table<? extends Row>  method2b(String parameter) {
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is direct consequence of raw type.

- `method1` is still a generic method : no issue.
- `method2b` is not anymore a generic method but override the method in  `Agent` : no issue (except the safety warning though, due to the unchecked conversion)
- `method2a` is not anymore a generic method but **does not override anything**

`method2a` is seen declared like this from `FinalAgent`, after compilation :

```
public Table method2a(List parameter)
```

But defined like this in `FinalAgent` :

```
public FinalTable method2a(List<String> parameter)
```

And now you are **stuck**. Same erasure but does not override correctly `method2a`

Here is a simple example :

```
public interface Foo
{
    public void bar(List a);
}

public class FooChild implements Foo
{
    @Override
    public void bar(List<String> a)
    {
    }
}
```

It gives `The method bar(List<String>) of type FooChild must override or implement a supertype method`

```
public interface Foo
{
    public void bar(List a);
}

public class FooChild implements Foo
{
    public void bar(List<String> a)
    {
    }
}
```

It gives `Name clash: The method bar(List<String>) of type FooChild has the same erasure as bar(List) of type Foo but does not override it`

Another example. This code compiles fine :

```
public interface Foo
{
    public void bar(List<String> a);
}

public class FooChild implements Foo
{
    public void bar(List<String> a)
    {   
    }   
}
```

This one does not :

```
public interface Foo
{
    public <T> void bar(List<String> a);
}

public class FooChild implements Foo
{
    public void bar(List<String> a)
    {   
    }   
}
```

It gives `Name clash: The method bar(List<String>) of type FooChild has the same erasure as bar(List<String>) of type Foo but does not override it`

As soon as `bar` becomes a generic method, it is seen with raw types and we can notice the same issue.

A different example of raw type issue : [Name clash when overriding method of generic class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27230928/name-clash-when-overriding-method-of-generic-class)

Comment: Where is there a raw type? Why is there an unchecked conversion?

Comment: `method2a` is seen with raw type in `Agent` because it's a generic method with the generic type T

Comment: The unchecked conversion comes from `FinalTable`. The compiler can't confirm it's a `<T extends Row> Table<T>` in `method2b`

Comment: Then why is it allowed altogether? Methods don't generally become raw unless they're associated with an explicitly raw type. In this case, there are no raw types, just an invalid override.

Comment: I added another example in my response.

Comment: @shmosel, what would you expect the raw type for FinalTable to be if 

`public abstract class Agent {
    public abstract FinalTable method2a(List<String> parameter);
}`

The raw type would be: "FinalTable".  Hence, 
public abstract `FinalTable method2a(List parameter);` would be a valid raw type.  This is consistent with the above example as `FinalTable method2a(String parameter);` is a valid raw type.